# Can't update my Ubuntu phone with phablet-flash

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I already have a Ubuntu Phone up and running on my Nexus 4. Now I wanted to update it with "phablet-flash" which tells me:

```
error: insufficient permissions for device
Error while executing adb shell getprop ro.cm.device 
Make sure the device is connected and viewable by running 'adb devices'
Ensure you have a root device, one which running 'adb root' does not return an error
```

"adb devices" shows:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I'm using a different PC than I used for installation.

How do I get access to the phone again so I can do an update?

Comment: Check the permissions on the current p.c.

Comment: Could You please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

***I don't have a Nexus 4 (only 7's and a 10) to test this, but ..***

### **Step 1.**

Re-start the device:

**Press and hold <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> buttons, for 5-7 seconds.**

You should now be at the *Bootloader* screen ('green START' )

### **Step 2.**

**Use the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> button twice**, to show 'Recovery Mode' (in red)

**Then press <kbd>Power</kbd>**, to restart in 'Recovery Mode'.

This will first show the Google logo for 4-6 seconds ..

Then change to Recovery Mode (with a Ubuntu logo in white circle).

### **Step 3.**

You should now be able to verify a USB connection.

**`adb devices`** should return 'recovery'

You can now download a fresh install to device.

Make sure **only** the target device is connected. *This will **not** verify the device attached, and will simply install software for a **Nexus 4** (mako).*

**`phablet-flash -b -d mako`**

### **UPDATE** (10-Aug-2013 onwards)

syntax now changed to:

**`phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b -d mako`**

---

***If this does not succeed, restore the device to Android (factory) settings.***